# How proxy authentication works before first user login?

Tags: macos, keychain, proxy, root

For the creation of a tool which make uses of system proxy preferences, I am trying to understand their keychain usage:

From my current understanding, on MacOS (Catalina) the system preferences for proxies are

- System wide (not per user)
- Per network interface (e.g. wifi or wired)

So I managed to get proxy parameters and this seems to work fine in both user-mode and root-mode.

However, **the proxy credentials (password) is stored in the keychain tool, more specifically in `login.keychain`which is user specific**.

For example, if the proxy is named "proxy_test", I can retrieve the proxy password with the following command in user-mode:

```
$ security find-internet-password -s "proxy_test" -g
    ...
    password: "password_test"
```

However, as root user the keychain is not accessible:

```
$ sudo su
$ security find-internet-password -s "proxy_test" -g
    security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

My conclusion is: Even if proxy preferences are system-wide, the credentials for proxy are saved in a user-specific keychain.

My tool is supposed to be a daemon running with root privileges, maybe before the first user had logged-in. In consequence this question: How is this supposed to work?

- Is it possible that macOS establishes a network through proxy before the first login? In this case, which user credentials will it use?
- Seems reasonable to create system-wide keychain and store the credentials there, but this is not how usually users works, so it would not work in most of the cases.
- Or probably I am just very wrong in some of my conclusions.

The question can be summarized as:

**How would a daemon running as root before the first user login access proxy credentials (password) from the keychain which are user-specific?**

Comment: Have you checked about Automatic Proxy? you can make .pac file and configure as automatic proxy configuration: http://localhost/proxy.pac . Hope this resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, I had a look to both: PAC and WPAD, but I want to cover also basic configurations like Http proxy and socks with authentication.